# Get hardware information of EC2 instance i.e. t2.micro uisng C# (AWS SDK)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk, asp.net-core-2.0

How to get all **hardware information of an EC2 instance** using C#.Net.

I am getting only **InstanceType** as t2.micro etc. etc. but I am not getting any hardware information of that Instancetype as Amazon sites are displaying. Attaching a screenshot for better understanding.

I have tried with below code but no success on that.

```
DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = client.DescribeInstances();
List<Reservation> reservation = describeInstancesResponse.Reservations;
var allInstance = reservation.SelectMany(x => x.Instances).ToList();
```

This is retrieving all information of EC2, but it contains only Instance Type, not with details.

[image]

Please suggest! thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help:  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Pricing/TPricingClient.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Pricing/TPricingClient.html)

Comment: There are no API calls that return hardware information.

Comment: But how the Amazon is displaying all information of instance type like t3.small has 2vCPU, Memory 2 GB storage EBS only etc.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hardware information are you trying to get?  The ec2 instance metadata contains some information such as mac.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories

Comment: I am trying to get information of Instance Type i.e. t2.micro has 1 VPC, 1 GB Memory, Internal Storage EBS only and its cost per hour etc.